# How to avoid creating several objects when applying casts?

Tags: c#, .net

At the moment I am using several objects in order get a property from an event that require multiple casts.

I am concerning if there is a better, possibly shorter way how to do this.

```
System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs eventTrack = (System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)e;
FluidKit.Controls.ElementFlow fluidItem = (FluidKit.Controls.ElementFlow)eventTrack.OriginalSource;
Client.DataModel.Advertisement adv = (Client.DataModel.Advertisement)fluidItem.ClickedItem;

string test = adv.ShopId.ToString();
```

Comment: Any suggestions for a better tittle are welcome :-)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Using multiple lines is the most readable way. You could however using implicitly typed variables (using `var`).

Comment: Agree with @DominicKexel. You are already doing it in the most readable way. (Note that you are NOT creating multiple objects!)

Comment: Thanks all guys for your feedback

Comment: @DominicKexel: by using var he will not get rid of the casting, (unless he defines his own implicit conversion between types)

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou I never said he will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there isn't much you can do about it - you can try constructs like

```
Advertisement adv = ((e as RoutedEventArgs).OriginalSource as ElementFlow).ClickedItem as Advertisement;
```

but this is quite ugly. There is also method with `dynamic` keyword that is avaliable in .NET 4:

```
dynamic eventArgs = e;
dynamic adv = e.OriginalSource.ClickedItem;
```

but this has a disadvantage of performance impact.

I think the way you have it (maybe without those namespaces) is the best for code readability while maintaining low performance impact.

Comment: I don't like your usage of the `as` keyword, because it would silence wrong cast type (return null if the type is not the same), compared to classic cast. Also, the dynamic code has a performance cost. It can be acceptable, but it has to be taken into consideration.

Comment: @SteveB I've mentioned performance impact of `dynamic` and masking you are talking about is just simple problem with `NullRefferenceException` instead of `InvalidCastException`. In addition to that, in newest version of C# they plan to create even more fun thing - `?.` operator which will return null if object is null or refference to whatever field or property you are trying to get to.

Answer (score 5):

You can use multiple casting i the same line:

```
string adv = ((Client.DataModel.Advertisement)(((FluidKit.Controls.ElementFlow)(((System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)e).OriginalSource)).ClickedItem)).ShopId.ToString();
```

Or you can use the `dynamic` keyword as Migol mentioned